# AppCompat theme file location

Tags: android

I'm trying to find where `AppCompat` styles are defined.
I've browsed `/sdk/platforms/android-XX/data/res/values/` but without success.
Is there a chance that they packed inside some platform jars?

Comment: This might help: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.style.html
Although I don't understand why you need to find these...

Comment: @IshitaSinha I'm interested in their hierarchy, which attributes are defined at each level.

Answer (score 0):

> \sdk\platforms\android-22\data\res\values

[image]

Comment: Strange, nothing there. I run OSX, maybe it's the OS difference? Theme.Material are available, but not Theme.AppCompat.

Comment: Ok , i dont have OSX but , i will check on Linux ubuntu OS let you know if i find something there .

Comment: @Bord81 I am running macOS High Sierra (10.13.3), and these files are definitely there. You need to check `/Users/yourusername/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-XX/data/res/values`. I am not sure if you are looking at the correct directory. Here's a reference: https://imgur.com/a/xvBjN

Comment: @IshitaSinha The path is correct and I see very similar list but still no files containing AppCompat.

Comment: @Bord81 Right. Sorry for the wrong path. Here: `/Users/yourusername/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values`

Comment: In the `/Users/yourusername/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/` I have no `/support` folder, only `gapid` and `m2repository`.